# How to setup Serilog with AzureEventHub

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, serilog, azure-eventhub

I want to use Serilog with the sink AzureEventHub, but I can't find any documentation on how to set it up.

I am running an ASP.NET MVC Core project.

Anyone got an idea or can give a clue to the solution?

Answer (score 2):

It would be great to have more documentation on that sink, for sure, but overall sinks configurations are pretty standard, as most sinks usually expose extension methods on Serilog's `LoggerSinkConfiguration` class, which together with intellisense in Visual Studio, can give you everything you need from the point of view of configuration.

Just make sure you install `Serilog` and the `Serilog.Sinks.AzureEventHub` sink.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.AzureEventHub" Version="4.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then at the beginning of your app, create an `EventHubClient` that you can pass through to `WriteTo.AzureEventHub`... You just need a valid connection string.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;
using Serilog;

namespace SerilogAndAzureEventHub
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EventHubClient eventHubClient =
                EventHubClient.CreateFromConnectionString(
                    "Endpoint=sb://a;SharedAccessKeyName=b;SharedAccessKey=c;EntityPath=d");

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                .WriteTo.AzureEventHub(eventHubClient)
                .CreateLogger();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out!

Comment: Thank you very much, I tested it and worked like a charm.